How can filter and retrieve specific records from big data efficiently using Python/Pyspark in Google Colab medium?
I'm struggling with a data engineering problem:
Dataset Characteristics



public dataset
duration
Total #VMs
Dataset size




AzurePublicDatasetV2
30 consecutive days
2,695,548 (~2.6M )
235GB (156GB compressed) [198 files]




Situation
I need to read 195 gzip files and filter some interested vmid records from time-series data. Due to the fact that the quality of data collection (the early time records for all vmids are on early files and the latest records are stored in the last files), I need to read all files and filter based on the interested vmid_lists. The problem I'm using Google Colab medium for my analysis and it has limited computation resources it crashes if naively I open each file and decompress and concat the dataframes using pandas. This approach needs further resources but currently, I do not have access.

each file is around ~800MB and contains 1M rows.

|   timestamp | vmid                                                             |   mincpu |   maxcpu |   avgcpu |
|:-----------:|:-----------------------------------------------------------------|---------:|---------:|---------:|
|           0 | yNf/R3X8fyXkOJm3ihXQcT0F52a8cDWPPRzTT6QFW8N+1QPfeKR5//6xyX0VYn7X |  19.8984 |  24.9964 |  22.6307 |

To the best of my knowledge, there are new packages for read\load bigdata (except for Spark):

dask
polars

Let's say I want to efficiently collect and filter records of limited vmids (e.g. 4 out of ~2.6M) that exist in the list of-course the best is:

to select those that have 30 days data continuously or
to collect all vmid data individually and store them accordingly [e.g parquet files ]

try-outs
What I have tried so far is below which leads to the Out-of-Memory (OOM) error or crashes notebook:
import dask.dataframe as dd

dfs = []
for i in range(1,196):
  print(i)
  df = dd.read_csv(f"https://azurecloudpublicdataset2.z19.web.core.windows.net/azurepublicdatasetv2/trace_data/vm_cpu_readings/vm_cpu_readings-file-{i}-of-195.csv.gz", blocksize=None)
  df.columns = ['timestamp', 'vmid', 'mincpu', 'maxcpu', 'avgcpu']
  dfs.append(df)

# Combine dataframes
combined_df = dd.concat(dfs)

# Select top 20 vmid
#top_vmid_counts = combined_df["vmid"].value_counts().head(20) # when this not feasible


# How to select continuous time data for selected vmids ---> vmid_lists = ...
vmid_lists = ["yNf/R3X8fyXkOJm3ihXQcT0F52a8cDWPPRzTT6QFW8N+1QPfeKR5//6xyX0VYn7X", #30 days data continuously
              "4WstS6Ub3GzHun4Mzb6BxLldKvkEkws2SZ9tbBV3kfLzOd+QRVETcgqLjtc3mCbD",
              "5f2jDjOhz6v00WonXOAuZW0uPO4OXjf5t64xYvOefcKwb4v7mOQtOZEVebAbiQq7",
              "E3fjqJ4h2SLfvLl9EV6/w9uc8osF0dw9dENCHteoNRLZTp500ezV9RPfyeMdOKfu",
             ]

top_vmid = combined_df[combined_df["vmid"].isin(vmid_lists)]

# Compute the result
result=top_vmid.compute()

Assumption
I think considering the situation I explained, the proposed solution should have:

read all csv.gz files 1 by 1 till the last file
filter (if you use Pyspark better to cash the table by .cashe())
concat dataframe(s)
store under the name of each vmids [e.g .parquet or .csv ]
delete the csv.gz to avoid crashing

Question\Challenge
So what is the best practice to efficiently do this task during read\load phase to retrieve easily interested records in Google Colab medium with default set-up? Looking for a smart way to solve the problem without change in Colab plan
Any help will be highly appreciated

Colab notebook if one is interested to experiment: 
Potentially related posts I have found:

More efficient way to select partly records from a big file in Python
How can I efficiently filter a PySpark data frame with conditions listed in the dictionary?
Efficient storage and retrieval for heirarichal data in python
how filter data where there is just one word
Make piece of code efficient for big data
Elegant way to enable random access by "month" in parquet file


in pyspark, you don't have to read the files individually. just point pyspark to the folder containing the files and it can read all at once. if possible, it can use spark's pushdown-predicate to intelligently read the data files (not sure if it's possible with compressed files)

Do you know the vmid_lists length? Did you already use the vmtable.csv.gz? If you compute the difference between vmdeleted and vmcreated, you have 0 vms with 8640 values (302460*60 / 300) https://i.sstatic.net/7NgtOPeK.png

@Corralien thanks for your comment. Good catch from the repo for selecting interested  VM(s) and checking their lifetime. short answer I have not used vmtable.csv.gz but I checked their analysis in this notebook. From my own domain knowledge I know that the collected VM info for month is as follow: the data collector acquire data every 5 mins for each VM (VM created till VM terminated) means:

1h = 12 records, 1 day= 288 records, 1 month (30days)= 8640 records
Sadly I didn't understand 300 within the calculation (it is also in the notebook addressed in the repo). So far this sounds to me a matter of selecting VM(s) list or inventory table for VMs which is very good for selecting smartly VMs based on lifetime. As I mentioned I'm very interested in filtering VMs with the highest lifetime or the most-seen ones for my analysis (forecasting and regression of CPU usage).

Still, the main challenge is best practice to read all files & filter interested records based on vmid_lists  (potentially smartly with the longest VMs) considering the data collection quality.

1 hour = 12 recordings because there is data every 5 minutes (300 seconds). What is your end use case? The conversion of chronological data (timestamp) into functional data (vmid) will generate a lot of I/O (179241 small files, I/O intensive operations). You should have a good reason to do this!

thanks I understood now (5 mins=300 secs). End Usecase is VM recmmendation system based on behavior of every single VM using forecasting and regression of CPU usage. To use this public dataset and apply\experiment my proposal system I need to extract at least some individual VM records (preferably lmost-seens or long lifetime ones).  According to my Assumption in the post, I was hopping to find a elegant way to do it with limited  computation resources in GoogleColab medium. and extract VMs based on vmid and store them [e.g .parquet or .csv ] at least interested ones vmid_lists

so I'm looking for an elegant way to do this during the read\load data stage from gzip files and hopefully, after storing individual VM records under their own name vmid  [e.g .parquet or .csv ]. Then I can read single VM data [e.g data = pd.read_parquet("file.parquet.gzip") in a modern\efficient way] and pass it to my model for further analysis.

You can't (easily) add data to a parquet file, so you have to load all the data before creating individual vm files, which is not possible here. An alternative is to use a database (row oriented instead of column oriented like a parquet file). When using Colab, you cannot install an SQL server. However, you can use sqlite. After compiling each CSV into a database, you can extract a VM record with its ID.

Then I simply forget the .parquet format and keep with .csv format for storing, no problem. it was just proposed within my assumption to store in a(n) modern\efficient way if it makes sense for this problem.

It is not possible to random-access into gzipped files in general. (There are some indexing techniques available, but no general solution https://github.com/pauldmccarthy/indexed_gzip)
Dask and pyspark are designed to run over all your data in parallel. They will load a partition at a time and parse it as a pandas dataframe in memory, before performing any further filtering or aggregations. With gzip, this means each partition is one whole file, and so you are running out of memory.
Assuming your filtering produces a dataframe that fits in memory,
probably the best solution to this situation is to stream through the data using pandas chunkwise iteration, which will stream through a gzip file without filling memory
it = pd.read_csv(..., iterator=True)
for chunk in it.get_chunk():
    # filter & aggregate or write to file

This process can even be parallelised with dask (and probably spark) using the delayed mechanism ( https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed.html ) to run through all the files at once, since streaming all the data in a single thread will take a long time.

I used  df_chunks = pd.read_csv(file_path, compression='gzip', chunksize=100000) successfully however I used dask package without pressing on GoogleColab default computation resources. I appended filtered_chunks and concated them filtered_df = pd.concat(filtered_chunks). The whole process took 2h 39min 56s for a few VMs. Let's see if there is another elegant way to do it much more efficiently. please extend your answer for an executable code.

+1 about Dask and its delayed feature! that works also but I'm not sure if it is an efficient solution it takes time!

You have very limited resources on Colab Free Plan (2 CPUs and 14 GB of memory), so it is difficult to carry out parallel processing. In addition you do not have access to temporal databases like influxdb.
Converting chronological data (timestamp, csv) into functional data (vmid, parquet) consumes resources and time. Parquet files must be created at once and it is not possible (easily) to add data to an existing file. One alternative is to use a SQLITE database.
If we limit ourselves to 1000 VMs, we can obtain a database in around 20 minutes (on my machine WITHOUT parallel processing but with the Azure data already downloaded to my disk)
You have to find a compromise between performance in writing, reading and data size. I choose to create an index on the VMs (larger base, more time to create it) however the reading is instantaneous.
I used vmtable.csv.gz to select the machines with the longest lifetime (170,000) and keep the first thousand for the example. I also used Polars rather than Pandas (too slow for I/O operations) or Dask (single machine, 2 CPU...)
1. Create the database
To increase performance and database size, I replace the vmid string with a numerical values as ForeignKey in cpu table.
#!pip install adbc_driver_sqlite
import sqlite3
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os
import time
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import adbc_driver_sqlite.dbapi

DBNAME = 'traces.db'

create_vm_table = """\
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vm (
    id INTEGER,
    vmid VARCHAR,
    UNIQUE (vmid),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"""

create_cpu_table = """\
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cpu (
    id INTEGER,
    timestamp INTEGER,
    vmid INTEGER,
    mincpu REAL,
    maxcpu REAL,
    avgcpu REAL,
    FOREIGN KEY (vmid) REFERENCES vmid (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"""

# For reading performance don't use it if you load all data every time
create_vm_index = "CREATE INDEX idx_vm ON CPU (vmid)"

if os.path.exists(DBNAME):
    os.unlink(DBNAME)

with sqlite3.connect(DBNAME) as conn:
    conn.execute(create_vm_table)
    conn.execute(create_cpu_table)
    conn.execute(create_vm_index)
    conn.commit()

2. Select longest lifetime VMs
url = 'vmtable.csv.gz'  # or https://azurecloudpublicdataset2.../vmtable.csv.gz
vm = pl.read_csv(url, has_header=False, new_columns=['vmid', 'vmcreated', 'vmdeleted'], columns=[0, 3, 4])
lifetime = vm['vmdeleted'] - vm['vmcreated']
vm = (vm.with_columns(id=np.arange(len(vm)))
        .filter(lifetime == lifetime.max())
        .select(['id', 'vmid']))
vm = vm.head(1000)  # or use your vmid_list here

conn = adbc_driver_sqlite.dbapi.connect(DBNAME)
vm.write_database('vm', conn, if_table_exists='append', engine='adbc')

3. Process CSV files
schema = {'timestamp': pl.UInt32, 'vmid': pl.String, 'mincpu': pl.Float32, 'maxcpu': pl.Float32, 'avgcpu': pl.Float32}
headers = list(schema)

for i in range(1, 196):
    file = f'vm_cpu_readings-file-{i}-of-195.csv.gz'  # or https://azurecloudpublicdataset2.../vm_cpu...
    start = time.time()

    # Extract data
    df = pl.read_csv(file, has_header=False, new_columns=headers, schema=schema)
    df = df.join(vm, on='vmid', how='semi')  # keep only wanted VMs

    # Replace string vmid to a numerical values (see vm table)
    df = df.with_columns(vmid=pl.col('vmid').replace(vm['vmid'], vm['id']).cast(pl.UInt32))

    conn = adbc_driver_sqlite.dbapi.connect(DBNAME)
    df.write_database('cpu', conn, if_table_exists='append', engine='adbc')

    end = time.time()
    print(f"Processing '{file}' in {end-start:.2f}sec")

Output:
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-1-of-195.csv.gz' in 4.72sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-2-of-195.csv.gz' in 4.90sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-3-of-195.csv.gz' in 4.77sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-4-of-195.csv.gz' in 4.96sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-5-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.00sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-6-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.09sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-7-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.10sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-8-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.14sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-9-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.01sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-10-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.17sec
...
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-186-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.83sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-187-of-195.csv.gz' in 6.06sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-188-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.93sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-189-of-195.csv.gz' in 6.08sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-190-of-195.csv.gz' in 6.01sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-191-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.85sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-192-of-195.csv.gz' in 6.07sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-193-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.93sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-194-of-195.csv.gz' in 5.93sec
Processing 'vm_cpu_readings-file-195-of-195.csv.gz' in 1.60sec

Note: For 179241 VM (with a lifetime of 2591400 sec, ~30 days). The final database is ~90 GB and each file is processed in ~60 seconds (fast at the start, longer at the end because of the index update)
Usage:
conn = adbc_driver_sqlite.dbapi.connect(DBNAME)
%time pl.read_database("SELECT * FROM cpu WHERE vmid IN (3, 18, 20, 15428, 15482) ORDER BY vmid, timestamp", conn)

# Output
CPU times: user 173 ms, sys: 211 ms, total: 384 ms
Wall time: 1.38 s

shape: (43_041, 6)
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ id      ┆ timestamp ┆ vmid  ┆ mincpu    ┆ maxcpu    ┆ avgcpu    │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ i64       ┆ i64   ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 26      ┆ 0         ┆ 3     ┆ 19.691057 ┆ 22.76716  ┆ 21.19558  │
│ 1082    ┆ 300       ┆ 3     ┆ 20.296198 ┆ 22.978518 ┆ 21.328156 │
│ 2037    ┆ 600       ┆ 3     ┆ 19.605423 ┆ 22.533613 ┆ 21.007982 │
│ 3046    ┆ 900       ┆ 3     ┆ 19.765459 ┆ 22.417776 ┆ 20.970156 │
│ 4027    ┆ 1200      ┆ 3     ┆ 19.499418 ┆ 22.341551 ┆ 20.977489 │
│ …       ┆ …         ┆ …     ┆ …         ┆ …         ┆ …         │
│ 8592037 ┆ 2590200   ┆ 15482 ┆ 4.034184  ┆ 7.431005  ┆ 4.764327  │
│ 8593106 ┆ 2590500   ┆ 15482 ┆ 4.000383  ┆ 4.961967  ┆ 4.537936  │
│ 8594063 ┆ 2590800   ┆ 15482 ┆ 4.099423  ┆ 7.335196  ┆ 4.769817  │
│ 8595071 ┆ 2591100   ┆ 15482 ┆ 3.784071  ┆ 5.007956  ┆ 4.530192  │
│ 8596053 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 15482 ┆ 4.306904  ┆ 26.457718 ┆ 7.602234  │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘

conn = adbc_driver_sqlite.dbapi.connect(DBNAME)
%time pl.read_database("SELECT * FROM cpu", conn)

# Output
CPU times: user 3.23 s, sys: 303 ms, total: 3.53 s
Wall time: 3.71 s

shape: (8_596_106, 6)
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ id      ┆ timestamp ┆ vmid  ┆ mincpu   ┆ maxcpu    ┆ avgcpu    │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ i64     ┆ i64       ┆ i64   ┆ f64      ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 0         ┆ 283   ┆ 5.355688 ┆ 33.903969 ┆ 9.426538  │
│ 2       ┆ 0         ┆ 898   ┆ 1.802976 ┆ 3.029618  ┆ 2.167491  │
│ 3       ┆ 0         ┆ 975   ┆ 0.276153 ┆ 1.940738  ┆ 0.768099  │
│ 4       ┆ 0         ┆ 1111  ┆ 5.921712 ┆ 8.36966   ┆ 6.789796  │
│ 5       ┆ 0         ┆ 309   ┆ 4.956732 ┆ 53.031315 ┆ 12.829752 │
│ …       ┆ …         ┆ …     ┆ …        ┆ …         ┆ …         │
│ 8596102 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 14380 ┆ 3.113321 ┆ 10.085616 ┆ 5.95079   │
│ 8596103 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 14525 ┆ 2.226282 ┆ 7.649525  ┆ 4.047262  │
│ 8596104 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 14405 ┆ 5.784489 ┆ 19.774389 ┆ 9.419931  │
│ 8596105 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 14369 ┆ 3.025543 ┆ 4.971849  ┆ 4.034433  │
│ 8596106 ┆ 2591400   ┆ 14824 ┆ 1.802819 ┆ 4.075792  ┆ 2.4867    │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


I receive the error: AttributeError: 'AdbcSqliteConnection' object has no attribute 'split' in vm.write_database('vmid_lists', conn, if_table_exists='append', engine='adbc') when I tried your solution in GoogleColab notebook

also AttributeError: module 'polars' has no attribute 'String' in line schema = {'timestamp': pl.UInt32, 'vmid': pl.String, 'mincpu': pl.Float32, 'maxcpu': pl.Float32, 'avgcpu': pl.Float32}

Did you update your packages: pip install -U polars adbc_driver_sqlite?

I did but something is wrong with it. You can check the notebook or this screenshot

@Mario. adbc_driver_sqlite not adbc_driver_sql ;)

Can you check this notebook please. Don't forget to create a folder SO78509755 at the root of your Google Drive.

I wish you could have shared SO78509755 file so I could put it in my drive folder. You also forgot to store interested VMs individually for further analysis. Please, check your shared notebook. At the end of day, I will award you bounty since you fulfilled the requirements mentioned in the description of the expected bounty. we can figure out and fix the rest, no problems. So far it seems this is an efficient solution with the time measurements you have shown at the time of the bounty question. we stay in touch till fix it.

I will select your solution as the answer once we have fixed but I passed the bounty to you. :)
